# rEFInd can't find Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-7, refind

I had to install Linux in UEFI mode, but my Windows 7 is not UEFI. Therefore, I can't use my UEFI GRUB to boot Windows. To solve this problem I downloaded rEFInd. However, rEFInd can't find my Windows installation and it doesn't show up in the list when starting up (even after pressing `esc` to update the list). I have uncommented the `scanfor` line in `refind.conf` and added `hdbios` as one of the options without any success. I also uncommented uefi_deep_legacy_scan, but that didn't make any difference. I have tried adding a manual entry to `refind.conf`, but I probably did not do it right since my entry didn't even show up on the list.

Because of this I have not been able to boot Windows at all since installing Linux. What can I do to fix this? Is my Windows installation simply broken or can it be added to `refind.conf`? I would really appreciate any help with this.

**Edit**:
This is the output of `lsblk`:

```
root@kali:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 365.4G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   285M  0 part /boot
├─sda6   8:6    0  65.2G  0 part /home
├─sda7   8:7    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda8   8:8    0   190M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda9   8:9    0  18.6G  0 part /
```

And this is the output of `parted --list`:

```
root@kali:~# parted --list
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ACF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  368MB  367MB   primary   ntfs
 2      368MB   393GB  392GB   primary   ntfs
 3      393GB   495GB  102GB   extended
 5      393GB   393GB  299MB   logical   ext4
 6      403GB   473GB  70.0GB  logical   ext4
 9      473GB   493GB  20.0GB  logical   ext4
 7      493GB   495GB  1999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 8      495GB   495GB  199MB   logical   fat32           boot, esp
```

/dev/sda8 is the partition I use to boot (and also the one where rEFInd and GRUB is installed). /dev/sda1 is the disk with the Windows loader I think.

**Edit 2**: The most important thing here isn't really to add Windows to my boot loader (although that would be great), but just being able to boot it once in a while is enough. Again, I would really appreciate any help at all.

**Edit 3**: I read at [this page](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/resize-linux-partition-safely/) that shrinking Windows partitions with Linux tools can break the Windows installation. Does that seem likely? (I used GParted to shrink /dev/sda2 when installing Linux). I have not been able to boot Windows once since the Linux installation. Right after it, my computer said no OS was installed and I had to select GRUB manually from HP UEFI Start-up menu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you [edit] your question and provide the output of `lsblk` and `parted --list`?

Comment: With OSes installed in different modes, the only way to (dual)boot is by changing the mode each time at UEFI settings. Neither Grub nor any other tool can help you with that.

Comment: @CelticWarrior [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/851948/628749) suggests otherwise

Comment: Have you tried that solution and it worked? I guess not otherwise you wouldn't be here. Even the overly optimistic author of rEFInd states that: *rEFInd can boot a BIOS-mode boot loader on most EFI-based computers, but not on all of them. A few early EFIs used an EFI layered atop a conventional BIOS, rather than an EFI with a CSM. rEFInd won't be able to redirect to a BIOS-mode boot loader on those early EFIs.* A more accurate assessment would say it may work in a few machines, not the other way around as implied.

Comment: CelticWarrior, I must take exception to your comment. I am the author of rEFInd and I am *very* aware of current developments in the EFI world and of the history of those developments. At present, most shipping EFIs provide the CSM support upon which rEFInd relies, but some EFIs (mostly older ones and 32-bit EFIs on very low-end machines) do not. Note that I am *not* claiming that rEFInd will definitely work for tjespe; I simply don't know enough about the EFI to say with certainty either way.  I am not "overly optimistic" about this -- but it is a niche feature needed by few people.

Comment: @RodSmith Okay, my machine is new this year and 64-bit. Do you know how I can make rEFInd detect Windows 7 or how I can add it manually?

Comment: What you describe above (uncommenting `scanfor` and adding `hdbios`) should work. If the firmware doesn't have a CSM, rEFInd should then complain when you boot. If you did this and don't see any new BIOS options, it could be a typo, so double-check that. It could also be that your disk is being miscategorized as external, in which case you'd need `biosexternal`, or even conceivably `cd`, instead of `hdbios`. Cut-and-paste the `scanfor` line for me to see if none of this works. All that said, as I noted in your other question, there are other options you can pursue, and one may be preferable.

Comment: I am unsure if this helps in any way but I experience something similar on my Macbook Pro 17" Early 2011. I had successfully installed and used for a while a dual boot with rEFInd using OS X and Windows 7. Then, I added a third partition in between the other two. From that moment on Windows is not found any more. I can select the second boot option but it won't start because nothing bootable is found there.

Comment: @Ben This may be the case for me as well. There are several parititions between my Ubuntu installation and Windows. Aditionally it seems like my Ubuntu installation is  in some kind of group (extended file system).

Comment: I read that Windows should be installed on a partition smaller than 4. But i am unsure about that. An Ubuntu installation with a virtual file system should be normal.