# update-grub: Windows 7 (Legacy mode) + Ubuntu 16.04 (UEFI)

Tags: grub2, windows-7, grub-efi

My BIOS has a problem that when legacy mode is enabled, the BIOS is working, but isn't graphically visible. In other words, I have to enable/disable it blindly.

I've installed Ubuntu with UEFI enabled.
I've installed Windows 7 in Legacy mode.

```
/sda1 /boot/efi (FAT)
/sda2 /boot
/sda3 /
/sdb1 "System Reserved" (NTFS)
/sdb2 C: (NTFS)
```

I've tried manually adding Windows to the grub config, but it gives me an error

```
insmod: could not load module ntfs: No such file
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

**UPDATE: Duplicate**

[duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851892/add-a-non-uefi-boot-target-to-an-uefi-grub/851948#851948)

Comment: Grub cannot switch modes. Can you select the boot device sdb (some function key at power-on)?   What hardware do you have, some will boot in either mode, with a preference you can set for one.

Comment: The BIOS allows selecting boot device, but since I cannot see it when Legacy mode is enabled, it's not possible.

Comment: Is there a way to install an UEFI-method of booting Windows 7? I've tried creating a modified boot USB with UEFI support, but without any luck. I could perhaps use Windows 8 instead, but I really hate the way it functions...